# Difference between a statement as third statement in for loop vs. in body

Tags: java, for-loop

For the for loop, I learned that it's of the form

```
    for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
        <body>
    }
```

What's the difference between exchanging `statement 3` for the last statement in the body, or with any statement such that order can be permuted? (The last part is a bit of a tautology, but I don't mean it in that way.) I imagine readability would be the biggest factor, but is there an actual difference in how the machine runs? I'm new to coding. This is Java, but I don't mind generalized answers to any language.

I tried

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        System.out.println("abc's");
    }
```

and

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; System.out.println("abc's")) {
        ++i;
    }
```

and both codes printed out 4 lines of "`abc's`". I imagine that if some lines in the body did something to the value of `i`, then I wouldn't be able to switch the `++i` line with those lines, but can I think of the third statement in the for loop as the "last" statement in the body, or is there a more inherent difference?

Comment: @GillesQuénot I added Java, but I won't do that next time, thank you.

Comment: If the loop body contained a `continue`, that would skip an increment that's at the bottom of the loop (possibly resulting in an infinite loop), but wouldn't skip an increment that's in the third `for` clause.

Comment: By the way, *statement 2*, if present, must be resolvable to a single `boolean`.  Java allows *statement 1* and / or *statement 3* to be coma separated lists of statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Difference between a statement as third statement in for loop vs. in body ...*
>
> *... What's the difference between exchanging `statement 3` for the last statement in the body, or with any statement such that order can be permuted? (The last part is a bit of a tautology, but I don't mean it in that way.) ..."*

There is not much of a restriction, it's just a way to organize the code.
Here is the *Java* tutorial.

*[The for Statement (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)*.

> ```java
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> - The *initialization* expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> - When the *termination* expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> - The *increment* expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

And, here is an excerpt from *Wikipedia*.

*[Wikipedia – For loop – FOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#FOR_)*.

> *Another form ... requires 3 parts: the [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)) ([loop variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant)), the [condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), and the advancement to the next iteration. All these three parts are optional.<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#cite_note-1)</sup> This type of "semicolon loops" came from [B programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)) ...*

The *for-loop* was created because of how often a loop required an accompanying value.

Thus, there is essentially no difference between the following two loops.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        
}
```

```java
int i = 0;
while (i < 100) {
    i++;
}
```

You can even add the *i* statement, from your example.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i, System.out.println("abc's")) {

}
```

> *"... I imagine readability would be the biggest factor, but is there an actual difference in how the machine runs? I'm new to coding. This is Java, but I don't mind generalized answers to any language. ..."*

With most coding languages, readability is a major role, *Java* is one of them, *[Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)* is another.
You'll find most of the syntax is based off of readability; *Java* expects their code to read similar to a sentence.

There shouldn't be much of a difference in how the code performs, the compiler will have ultimately converted any *for-loop* and *while-loop* code into similar *machine-code*.

If you're interested in this aspect of *Java*, I recommend reviewing *[Java: The Complete Reference, 12th Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-the-complete/9781260463422/)*.
This series was published by *Oracle* for several years; I imagine they endorse it.

> *"... can I think of the third statement in the for loop as the "last" statement in the body, or is there a more inherent difference?"*

It would need to be the last statement, as to not disrupt any mutual access.

Answer (score 3):

Just comparing the order of statement 1, statement 3, and body_last_statement...

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    <body>
    body_last_statement;
}
```

performs
`statement 1 → body_last_statement → statement 3 → body_last_statement → ... → body_last_statement → statement 3`

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; body_last_statement) {
    <body>
    statement 3;
}
```

performs
`statement 1 → statement 3 → body_last_statement → ... → statement 3 → body_last_statement`

So in the code like yours

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

prints **0** first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; System.out.println("abc's")) {
    ++i;
}
```

prints **1** first.

Also, if `<body>` has some `if (...) continue;` then, it can fall into an infinite loop like

```
// Print only even numbers
for (i=1; i<=10; System.out.println(i)) {
    // Skip printing odd numbers
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        continue;
    i++;
}
```

which prints

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
(forever)
```